# Is there a way to use if..else logic in conditional filters in ansible?

Tags: linux, ansible

I want to hard code 2 different values based on variable stdout in a single play.If a service is running then i want to hard code value as good else bad.How to use this logic in ansible?

I can able to hard code one value based on status result.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:

  tasks:
  - name: load var from file
    include_vars:
      file: /tmp/var.json
      name: imported_var

  - name: Checking mysqld status
    shell: service mysqld status
    register: mysqld_stat

  - name: Checking mysqld status
    shell: service httpd status
    register: httpd_stat

  - name: append more key/values
    set_fact:
      imported_var: "{{ imported_var| default([]) | combine({ 'mysqld_status': 'good' })}}"
    when: mysqld_stat.rc == 0

  - name: append more key/values
    set_fact:
      imported_var: "{{ imported_var| default([]) | combine({ 'httpd_status': 'good' })}}"
    when: httpd_stat.rc == 0

  - name: write var to file
    copy:
      content: "{{ imported_var | to_nice_json }}"
      dest: /tmp/final.json
```

I want to hard code mysqld_status : Good if mysqld_stat.rc == 0 or mysqld-status: Bad if mysqld_stat.rc != 0.Is it possible to achieve in single play.(i.e) in single command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many of ways of approaching this problem.  You could just add a second `set_fact` that runs when `mysqld_stat.rc != 0`. In the following example, only one of the two `set_fact` tasks will run:

```
- name: append more key/values
  set_fact:
    imported_var: "{{ imported_var| default({}) | combine({ 'mysqld_status': 'good' })}}"
  when: mysqld_stat.rc == 0

- name: append more key/values
  set_fact:
    imported_var: "{{ imported_var| default({}) | combine({ 'mysqld_status': 'bad' })}}"
  when: mysqld_stat.rc != 0
```

You could instead use Ansible's ternary filter:

```
- name: append more key/values
  set_fact:
    imported_var: "{{ imported_var| default({}) | combine({ 'mysqld_status': (mysqld_stat.rc == 0)|ternary('good', 'bad') })}}"
```

Comment: Thanks @larsks. Ternary filter is the one i'm looking for